# reading Pcap and writing it to csv file python

Tags: python, string, csv, scapy, pcap

I'm reading a pcap file and trying to write it to a csv file with necessary data.
I used Scapy to read Pcap and could successfully fetch the package data, Now i'm trying to write to a csv file but endingup only with one data. Below is my code.

```
pkts = rdpcap('example.pcap')

for pkt in pkts:

    if IP in pkt:
        ip_src=pkt[IP].src
        ip_dst=pkt[IP].dst
    if TCP in pkt:
        tcp_dport=pkt[TCP].dport

    if ip_src == '10.116.206.114' and ip_dst == '10.236.138.184':
        print (str(ip_src) + str(ip_dst) + str(tcp_dport)) 

        csv_header = "IP_src,IP_drc,dst_port\n"

         s = ""
        for scr in str(ip_src):
            s+=str(scr)
        csv_header += s + ','

        s_ = ''
        for dst in str(ip_dst) :
            s_+=str(dst)
        csv_header += s_ + ','

        s_1 = ''
        for dst_tcp in str(tcp_dport):
            s_1 += str(dst_tcp)
        csv_header += s_1

        f = open("Pcap/test.csv", "w")
        f.write(csv_header)
```

Now i'm getting only one output in csv

[image]

if i print to check i get all output in log but not in csv, Please suggest me the proper way append the data into csv

Thanks!

Comment: You're repeatably opening the same file inside of the for-loop and overwriting it. I would suggest moving the opening of the file to before the for-loop, and also using a context-manager for the file-opening.

Comment: Sorry , I didnt get what your trying to say @HampusLarsson can you please explain indetail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @HampusLarsson commented, you are opening the file every iteration of the for loop. You should open the file before the loop.
This is the fixed code:

```py
pkts = rdpcap('example.pcap')

with open("Pcap/test.csv", "w") as f:
    for pkt in pkts:

        if IP in pkt:
            ip_src=pkt[IP].src
            ip_dst=pkt[IP].dst
        if TCP in pkt:
            tcp_dport=pkt[TCP].dport

        if ip_src == '10.116.206.114' and ip_dst == '10.236.138.184':
            print (str(ip_src) + str(ip_dst) + str(tcp_dport)) 

            csv_header = "IP_src,IP_drc,dst_port\n"

            s = ""
            for scr in str(ip_src):
                s+=str(scr)
            csv_header += s + ','

            s_ = ''
            for dst in str(ip_dst) :
                s_+=str(dst)
            csv_header += s_ + ','

            s_1 = ''
            for dst_tcp in str(tcp_dport):
                s_1 += str(dst_tcp)
            csv_header += s_1

            f.write(csv_header)
```

Note that we are using a context-manager (`with open(...) as ...:`), so the file will automatically close at the end of the scope, or in case an exception is raised.